# Why ng-show is not hiding a div and its content into my page?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, javascript-framework, ng-show

Gi everyone,
I am very new in **Angular** and I am finding the following problem trying to hide a div and its content into a view. I am trying to use the **NgShow** directive as explained in this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

I have the following situation. Into a component I have a view named **mail-datail-protocollo-sidebar.component.html**. It contains a div on which I have setted the **ng-show** directive, something like this:

```
<div class="info-box" ng-show="showSelectAOOUORLists">
    <div class="title-box">Lista AOO</div>
    <p-dropdown placeholder="Selezionare un AOO"
                [options]="aooList"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedAoo"
                optionLabel="Name"
                (onChange)="onChangeAoo($event)">
    </p-dropdown>

    <div *ngIf="selectedAoo">
        <div class="title-box" style="margin-top: 20px;">Lista UOR</div>
        <p-dropdown placeholder="Selezionare un reparto relativo all'AOO selezionato"
                    [options]="uorList"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedUor"
                    optionLabel="UnitaOperativaResponsabile">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>


    <div style="margin-top: 28px; width: 30%">
        <button *ngIf="selectedUor"
                type="button"
                pButton icon="fa-stamp"
                label="Invia al protocollo"
                (click)="inviaProtocollo($event)"></button>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see I setted **ng-show="showSelectAOOUORLists"** so in theory it should use the value of the boolean variable named **showSelectAOOUORLists** defined into the related controller class.

Then I have the controller class of the previous view, named mail-datail-**protocollo-sidebar.component.ts** that contains this boolean variable used to show or hide the previous div:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mail-detail-protocollo-sidebar',
    templateUrl: '/app/maildetail/mail-detail-protocollo-sidebar/mail-datail-protocollo-sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../app/maildetail/mail-detail-protocollo-sidebar/mail-detail-protocollo-sidebar.component.css']
})
export class MailDetailProtocolloSidebarComponent implements OnInit {

    showSelectAOOUORLists: boolean;
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
    .........................................................

    constructor(
        private mailsService: MailsService,

        private mailDetailProtocolloService: MailDetailProtocolloService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.showSelectAOOUORLists = false;
        ...............................................................
        ...............................................................
        ...............................................................
    }

    .........................................................
    .........................................................
    .........................................................
}
```

So, as you can see, basically at the moment I am setting to **false** the value of the **showSelectAOOUORLists** variable (into the **ngOnInit()**, so in theory before that the page is rendered) to hide the div and its content.

The problem is that this div is still shown on the page.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this behavior? Use **ng-show** is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **ng-show and ng-hide** are supported from Angular v1.x.x but in your code you're using an Angular version higher than 1 which ng-show/ng-hide are not supported.

Use `[hidden] or *ngIf` instead to show and hide your div

Example:

```
<div class="info-box" [hidden]="!showSelectAOOUORLists">

or 

<div class="info-box" *ngIf="showSelectAOOUORLists">
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` in angularJs component. YOu need to use either `*ngIf` or `[hidden]` to facilitate the ngShow functionality in angular 2.

```
<div class="info-box" *ngIf="showSelectAOOUORLists">
```

hidden

```
<div class="info-box" [hidden]="!showSelectAOOUORLists">
```